# Drupal URLs not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, clean-urls

I am using Drupal 7 and suddenly my URLs don't work anymore. I upgraded Apache and PHP, but that was my only change. It were just minor version changes.

Now my problem. When I access my main url, let's say `http://example.com`, I get a page not found error. If I access `http://example.com/?q=` it does work. I have not enabled clean URLs, but the .htaccess file is in place. Apparently I can't leave out the `?q=`, although it should not be necessary at all.

If you need any more information, please ask.

Edit:
It think it is weird that my page shows this: `The requested page "/http://example.com/" could not be found.` (the leading slash?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. The problem was a Google Chrome extension I was using, [Hosts Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hosts-manager/kpfmckjjpabojdhlncnccfhkfhbmnjfi). It broke my Drupal installation, so that was the problem. It took a while before I figured it out, and I now know you should **not** use this extension!

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the guidelines in drupal.org for 
[Clean URLs](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls)

Answer (score 2):

When you upgraded Apache, did you ensure that:

- Mod Rewrite was still enabled
- Allow Override is set to All in your http.conf for your docroot